# How to make a group in Long Look notification have only rounded corners on the bottom

Tags: ios, watchkit

On [apples site it shows](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/) a long look notification that has a group that looks like it is part of the upper sash. It has rounded corners only on the bottom. How can we achieve the same look?

Comment: Take a look at this question and my answer: "WKInterfaceGroup bottom corner radius": http://stackoverflow.com/a/28709891/1700857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to set a background image to the group, and the image will simulate the rounded corners at the bottom.
As you mentioned, you will probably don't want the rounded corners to be stretched badly as the group increases in height. To achieve this you can set bottom image insets in the assets catalog, so only the top part of the image will stretch.

Comment: So the image is the grey background with rounded corners... what happens then the text is a different size then the background?

Comment: The image will stretch together with the group. So if the text is longer, the group will re-size accordingly.

Comment: This works fine if I set the resizableImageWithCapInsets during willActivate. However if I set it inside the story board the image gets resized badly. This poses a problem because the static notification view cannot have this background. Also when adding the image during willActivate for a dynamic notification there is a delay before it is rendered on the simulator.

Comment: Just found out you can set the insets in the image assets. Well I feel silly. Thanks for the help. Please update your answer to include this and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Didn't thought about that... sorry for not solving your problem, that was my best shot :)